# Foundation range sliders only work after launching browser console

Tags: angularjs, browser, zurb-foundation

I'm coding an application using **AngularJS v1.3.0** and **Foundation 5.0.3**. In one of my pages, I have a a couple of fieldsets, each one containing a few [range sliders](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/range_slider.html). Something like this

```
<fieldset ng-repeat="element in list" id="element_{{element.ID}}">
  <legend>Element: {{element.name}}</legend>
  <div ng-repeat="subelement in element.list" id="subelement_{{subelement.ID}}">
    <div class="small-10 medium-11 columns">
      <div class="range-slider round" data-slider="50">
        <span class="range-slider-handle"></span>
        <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

The problem is **I can't move the sliders until I open the browser console**. It happens in Firefox and Chrome. I guess AngularJS defines some variables when the debug mode is activated in the browser, and this causes the problem. But I don't really know...

Any clues?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: are you using require.js

Comment: i think so .. because it seems like the view is not getting the foundation base js.. what are the console.log erros

Comment: Sorry for my delay. No errors in the console. I just can't move the sliders. More weird things: If I reload the page with the console open, I can't move them. I need to re-open the console again to do it. Or just change its position (from bottom to right, for example). So, it looks like there's a conflict between my app events (Foundation or Angular) and browser console's events. I'm new with JS, so, I'm totally lost.

Comment: For future reference: I've just finished the first version of [a module](https://github.com/csaftoiu/foundation-range-slider-angular) to use foundation sliders from angular.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the reference

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this run function to your angular app.

```
.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $(document).foundation();
    });
});
```

Comment: just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't have the range slider in it yet, if you are using angular with foundation you should check out this: http://pineconellc.github.io/angular-foundation/

Answer (score 0):

Foundation range slider port for Angular at https://github.com/fulup-bzh/RangeSlider